# Selenium goBack and wait

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have this selenium test (a part of it).

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>localhost:8091</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Rest objects</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Show')])[3]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertText</td>
    <td>xpath=(//div[not(div)][1])</td>
    <td>ID: 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>goBack</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Show')])[5]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>goBack</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>.
```

I use Selenium IDE in Firefox. When I run it slowly (toggle speed), it works well. However, when I try to run it faster, I get error at the step `<td>clickAndWait</td>` after `<td>goBack</td>`. The log says,

*Element xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Show')])[5] not found*.

My questions, how to go back and wait until the page is loaded before I perform other actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `waitForPageToLoad` command adter click on element till the page loaded and then perform other actions

Use Below code

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Show')])[5]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForPageToLoad</td>
    <td>10000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: After `click`, or maybe after `goBack`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks (@Trimantra Software Solution).

`waitForPageToLoad` this is what I needed.
From documentation:

```
waitForPageToLoad(timeout)
    Arguments:

        timeout - a timeout in milliseconds, after which this command will return with an error

    Waits for a new page to load.
```

This is my solution, I used `waitForPageToLoad` after `goBack`.

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>localhost:8091</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Rest objects</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Show')])[3]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertText</td>
    <td>xpath=(//div[not(div)][1])</td>
    <td>ID: 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>goBack</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForPageToLoad</td>
    <td>800</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Show')])[5]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>goBack</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Whenever you use `waitForPageToLoad` it will wait for complete page load within given timeframe. So in your case once you do back navigation  using `goBack` command and then using `waitForPageToLoad`, it will do first back navigation and wait till page get loaded, and then move to next action what you have written

Answer (score 0):

I see a goBackAndWait() variant of this command. That might work for you.

Typically I'd advise using a waitFor to ensure the page is back to where you want. Simplest that may work is waitForTitle if possible.
waitForElementPresent & waitForText also good ones to look at.